# Can't select layer in the Road Graph plugin QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, road, graph

I'm trying to use the Road Graph plugin in QGIS 2.2.0.

I have tried a few line shape files, but it won't let me select the layer (the option is greyed out). I've tried adding a 'SPEED' field and a 'Type' field but its still the same. The CRS is in the project format.

I can't see any other reason it wouldn't work?

Thanks,

Joe[image: Road Graph Dialogue]

Answer (score 3):

That's a known issue of QGIS 2.2 but it should be fixed in the dev version and will be in 2.4. See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9780